# Find by id but update subschema

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

So I've created the following model with a subschema (allocationAndLocationSchema). Each MovementSchema will have many embedded allocationAndLocationSchemas in it. I need to update individual allocationAndLocationSchemas and save them to the model.

I've tried doing a forEach on the subschema but updating that doesn't seem to work. Is there a simple solution to search for the model by id (createdByUserID) and the subschema by userID then update it's latitude and longitude?

Model and subschema:

```
var allocationAndLocationSchema = new Schema({
    roleID: String,
    roleTitle: String,
    userID: String,
    latitude: String,
    longitude: String,
    lastUpdated: Date
});

var MovementSchema = new Schema({
    dateCreated: Date,
    createdByUserID: String,
    dateEdited: Date,
    allocationAndLocation: [allocationAndLocationSchema]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its just raw  so, take idea from it.

`MovementSchema.findByIdAndUpdate({createdByUserID:req.body.createdByUserID,'allocationAndLocation.userID': req.body.userID},{$set:{allocationAndLocation.$.longitude:req.body.longitude ,allocationAndLocation.$.latitude : req.body.latitude},function(err,res){
//call back function
}`